# What can cause the [Ignore] attribute to be ignored?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a test suite with a few tests that are failing because the requirements have changed out from under them, necessitating code changes that break the tests.  It's not immediately obvious how to fix the tests, so for the moment I want to simply disable them.

I added the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.IgnoreAttribute` attribute to these tests, but they're still being run by Test Explorer.  I've considered the possibility that the test runner we're using would use its own mechanism, but that seems unlikely, as it responds to the `TestMethodAttribute` and `TestCategoryAttribute` attributes from the same namespace.  One of the tests looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Integration")]
[Ignore]
public void TestJobIntegrationDev01()
{
    //test code goes here
}
```

How do I determine why `Ignore` is not working in this case?

Comment: Please provice a [mcve]

Comment: @ThomasWeller A verifiable example of what, exactly?  This really feels like the kind of bug where, if I knew what was causing it, I would also know how to fix it and wouldn't have to ask here.

Comment: 2 OT flags for this, what the... not sure how much more about "programming" this Q could be. Come on people.

Comment: Is Ignore being (ahem) ignored when you run tests locally, or is it only happening as part of an automated build process?

Comment: @Polyfun It's being ign... errr... *disregarded* by Visual Studio's test runner.  I haven't even tried running the build yet.  (Without going into too many details, let's just say that doing so is far more complicated than it ought to be at my current workplace.)

Comment: @MasonWheeler: At least show us the using statements. It seems you have a solution that has problems with the Ignore attribute. Make a copy of it. Remove all code that is not required to run that one test. Then post the solution somewhere, preferably here. It should not be more than 1 class, right? SO will allow enough to post the CSPROJ file's XML if needed. For that reason (missing usings alone) the question IMHO is OT, because we don't have all the needed code.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: if you think it's a bug in VS, wouldn't it be great to post the exact version numbers, or do you want us to install everything from Visual Studio 98 upwards? For that reason, the question is too broad.